# .NET DbProviderFactory and Singleton

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton, dbproviderfactories

I am trying to build a generic connection class using DbProviderFactory, DbConnection and other abstract classes in System.Data.Common

I noticed that both DbProviderFactory and DbConnection have method to Create Command.

If I intend to implement Singleton pattern, on which object is it advisable (on DbProviderFactory object or DbConnection object)?

Answer (score 1):

You use the `DbProviderFactories` class to produce a `DBProviderFactory` for your chosen connector. Using this, and your connection string, you create a `DbConnection`. With this `DbConnection` you can create your `DbCommand` and use the `DbProviderFactory` to create your `Parameter` and add them. There's no need for a singleton.

Comment: Do I have to do this every time I need a connection to the database? I wanted to avoid this being executed over and over, which made me think in singleton grounds.

Comment: You can wrap your DbProviderFactory into a Singleton if you like? If you want, you can keep your current connection active too. It depends on how you want to solve it. But Singleton itself it not specifically necessary for the DbProvider based system.